# deploying a react app + nodejs api's application with docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, docker-build

[image]i tried to depling my react app to docker file and it just stop after this command
"docker build -t docker-expressjs-react ."
how can i fixing that?
i attached an image of my react app folder to help you understand my files paths
thanks for help

[image]

dockerFile

```
FROM node:14 AS ui-build


WORKDIR /usr/app/client/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY public/ ./public
RUN npm run build
FROM node:14 AS server-build
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY --from=ui-build /usr/app/client/build/ .client/build
WORKDIR /usr/app/server/
COPY server/package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY server/server.js ./

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000
  
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

server file

```
          let root = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build');
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(express.static(root));
        app.use('/*', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
        });
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        root = require('path').join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build');
        app.use(express.static(root));
        app.use('/*', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
        });
    }
    
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    
        next();
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => console.log(process.env.PORT || port));
```

Comment: Any body can help ??

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?  Can you describe, in text, what commands you're running, what output you're getting, and so on?  The screen shots of your IDE are very difficult to read and understand.